# How to set progress in custom long running timer job

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016, sharepoint-timer-job

I need some logical advice for setting progress in custom long running timer job (more than half an hour).

I have loop for more than 50k items in timer job Execute.

How to elegant update progress bar every minute or two using `SPJobDefinition.UpdateProgress(int percentage)` method?

I don't want update progress for each iteration in for-loop (too many progress updates).

sample code

```
 SPListItemCollection collListItems = list.GetItems();
    for (var i = 0; i < collListItems.Count; i++)
    { 
     //code
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make 10 or 20 updates then. I mean something like that:

```
var percentBlock = 10;
var updateBlock = collListItems.Count / percentBlock;
SPListItemCollection collListItems = list.GetItems();
for (var i = 0; i < collListItems.Count; i++)
{ 
    if(i % updateBlock == 0)
        SPJobDefinition.UpdateProgress(i / updateBlock * percentBlock);
    //code
}
```

I think this would be more fair updates than periodical.

Comment: I also think something like that would be more fair. Thanks for creative solution.:)